# Client Submitted Form to Create a Cron Job on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, rubygems, queue, delayed-job

Okay I decided to improve on what I am asking for help with verse just opening a new question on this. I believe I can accomplish the below if I know of a way that when a client submits a form on my Rails app a cron job is run, where the time for the cron job is selected by the user from a drop down menu. Is there a way to do this, I have been googling around for ideas but haven't found one.

**Old Question**

I am attempting to develop a system that would allow a user to upload a movie to my site and then have it played back at a certain time. The movies would be continuously streamed, so that at a certain time say after an hour, the next movie in the queue would play. I am wondering is there a gem or script that already does this? Or what is the best way to go about doing it, I thought doing it with jobs like cron or delayed-job, but I don't think that's the most efficient way to do this. Any advice would be appreciated.

p.s. I think a simplier way to explain it is, on YouTube you can queue up videos to be played, so could one do something similiar in rails, this would help towards my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user gets to decide the exact time of playback, you could use the [rufus-scheduler](http://rufus.rubyforge.org/rufus-scheduler/) gem.

Plug in your Time obtained from the user like so:

```
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new
scheduler.at @user_defined_time do
   some_method
end
```

Your `some_method` could work in tandem with a [socket.io](http://socket.io/) wrapper like [Juggernaut](https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut), which would send a message to the user's browser, which would execute some JS that would fetch the video and play it.

What you could do with this is basically sit around with your browser window open, and when the scheduled time is reached, the browser would fetch the appropriate video and play it.

If you need to implement a video queueing system, you could just enable users to queue up the videos they want to by ID, and then call the next video in the queue via means for a callback function which is triggered when the video has ended. The callback would query the database for the next video in the queue, fetch the video, and play it.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like it may be the best comprehensive model I am looking for if it doesn't work I'll certainly try the other solutions here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you even need to do the background stuff for just front-end scheduling.
Need not to even go for Juggernaut or any Cron Job thingy.

This all can simply be achieved by using JavaScript.
You can either use javascript's setTimeout() and clearTimeout() functions or add a sleep() before your ajax call.

here are the steps:

1. You load the first movie or just the page.
2. Make an ajax call within the setTimeout function. 
   Note: don't forget to assign the setTimeout() to a variable so that you can do clearTimeout(the_variable).
   here is the detailed usage: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp
3. setTimeout works as setTimeout(javascript_statement, milliseconds) ... these milliseconds should be the total time of the current movie or whatever time that's being set by the user subtracted from the current time which gives you milliseconds left to be played.
4. Send the current movie id in this ajax request, so that on server you can calculate which movie is to be played after the movie just played... by fetching the last movie played with this sent movie-id parameter.
5. I also believe you'd require some functionality like, only play the next movie when the current movie ends. So basically you can also replace the setTimeout() function for making the Ajax call with the movie-players function. Just make an ajax call to server when the movie-player completes playing the current movie... again sending the current movie-id in the request.
6. If even after the completion of current movie, you want to wait for the appropriate time  to start the movie, you need to make use of periodically_call_remote which sends a ajax requests after a set number of seconds.
7. And once on server, i.e. in your controller where you handle that ajax request, once you make sure you need to show the movie now, just replace the player container with the partial containing the player and the link to the newmovie with autoplay-on-load set to true.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the extremely popular [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) on projects that rely heavily on scheduled tasks, and it's great. It gives you a nice DSL to define your scheduled tasks instead of having to deal with crontab format. From the README:

```
Whenever is a Ruby gem that provides a clear syntax for writing and deploying cron jobs.
```

Example from the README:

```
every 3.hours do
  runner "MyModel.some_process"       
  rake "my:rake:task"                 
  command "/usr/bin/my_great_command"
end

every 1.day, :at => '4:30 am' do 
  runner "MyModel.task_to_run_at_four_thirty_in_the_morning"
end
```

Put your user defined parameters in above query. thats it.